# Double tags qgis and qgis-2.0

Tags: feature-request, tags, version-tags

I find it misleading with two tags for the same application QGIS. I think the qgis-2.0 should be dropped. We still have lots of people posting question in qgis tag when running qgis 2+.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see any advantage of having the [qgis-2.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2.0) tag. There are three QGIS releases per year and that means three new tags per year:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis2.0
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis2.2
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis2.4

I suggest we simplify and only keep the qgis tag.

Comment: I agree 2.5 is next month (September 2014) - but should the same be applied to all [tag:ArcGIS] tags?

Comment: Others will probably be more qualified to judge how helpful the arcgis version tag are. I assume we are not discussing removing the non-version tags (e.g. arcgis-server, arcgis-mobile) as well?

Comment: This would seem to fall under the general 'version tag' discussion. In fact, QGIS specifically has been mentioned at two other questions on the topic: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/using-version-tags and http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/how-to-tag-questions-that-involve-python-programming-language As touched on there, QGIS has a more frequent release schedule than ArcGIS. Whether 2.x 3.x etc vs 2.2 2.4 etc is more useful vs concise in terms of version tags I cannot say being unfamiliar with the extent of changes/and numbering scheme used for QGIS releases.

Answer (score 5):

While it could be construed as a double tag, technically it isn't. One is a software tag, one is a version tag.

[qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) should be applied to **all** questions related to the QGIS software, regardless of version. The version tag, such as [qgis-2.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2.0) is used only for questions where a) that is the version asker is using or b) the version has specific relevance to the question (ie something works a certain way only in 1.8 and not any other version). A or B depends on your philosophy as part of a larger discussion as mentioned below.

The question(s) I linked to in my comment to underdark's answer are on a similar subject have have some links to relevant faqs/blog posts/discussion/etc. on the use and formatting of version tags throughout the SE network. Since comments can be temporal, those questions are:

- [Using version tags?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/using-version-tags)
- [Tagging Questions that involve Python programming language?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/how-to-tag-questions-that-involve-python-programming-language)

The short summary is no two SEs seem to enforce a consistent standard and it's left up to the individual sites to determine how version tags are best used. Here on GIS.SE, our current 'policy' varies by the software - as evidenced by this and the linked questions. However there does seem to be general agreement that version tags *are* useful - just in different ways to different people, and the debate over what they (should) mean.

My personal philosophy, as I've stated elsewhere but applied to this specific question, is that the QGIS version tags are useful and should be kept - but only applied when version is relevant to a question. For example "2.4 broke my x" or "I have to use 1.8" or the issue is a specific bug present in a specific version.

Comment: Removing the version tags is information loss. So I would rather keep the version tags and add the 'general' `qgis` tag where it's still missing.

Comment: Is there any possibility of having of having the qgis tag added **automatically** to any question with a qgis-version tag? If a question doesn't have the plain qgis tag I usually don't see it.

Comment: @csk the 'auto-tagging' idea has been discussed before. It comes down to there being 5 tags available and not taking them up with automatic applications, or having them incorrectly applied. It's another argument for my view on version tag use, but a counter-solution (given to me when I asked the same/it was discussed) is searching tags for 'qgis' which will give you all questions with any tag that has qgis in it.

Comment: @ChrisW Searching for [qgis] yields *only* questions tagged with qgis. Other tags with qgis in them are not included.

Comment: @csk I may have phrased that badly. Searching *tags* for 'qgis' will return all tags with qgis in them. Using the normal question search with [qgis*] would in theory return all questions with a tag that has qgis in it, but the wildcard is bugged or restricted per blah's answer at Using Version Tags and in comments on the Python question linked in my answer. When I just tried it I only got three tags, not even the 20 mentioned elsewhere.