# Merging [qgis] and [qgis-3] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, version-tags

Being fairly new on GIS SE, I often wondered, why there is a `qgis` and a `qgis-3` tag. I can imagine it being once relevant, when QGIS 3 was fairly new, and a lot of people still used a 2.x LTR, plugins weren't all adapted etc.

I found [Keep or delete [qgis-3] version tag?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925) from nearly 5 years ago, discussing to merge multiple tags. I want to discuss now whether a seperate `qgis-3` tag is still relevant or could be merged into a single `qgis` tag. We're at version 30 now, I don't believe there are many users left still using QGIS 2.

Since joining these Q&A sites, I wonder at every question I post, if using `qgis-3` along with `qgis` would help me get faster answers. Never have I ever considered using only one, because my question does not fit into the other category.

A similar discussion was previously held for `qgis-2` as  [Double tags qgis and qgis-2.0](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3737), providing different views on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

In the early days of this site there was considerable debate about whether and when to use version tags.  At that time, I was a proponent of version tags.

However, I now think it is far better to always mention the version being used within the body of a question (or answer), and to simply use a product tag.

Consequently, I would be in favour of merging the [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3) tag into the [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) tag.  This would seem to align with an earlier [answer from @underdark](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3738/115) when discussing the value of version/double tags for QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I personally agree with [PolyGeo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5430/186820), one could argue that once QGIS evolves to 4.x, it will possibly be again crucial to seperate questions asking about 3.x and 4.x from each other (same problem as why `qgis-3` exists in the first place).

That would be an opinion against merging said tags.

Then once again, the question arises, wether it would be wise to automatically add the `qgis` tag to all questions tagged `qgis-3` to make searching for tags easier as mentioned [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/double-tags-qgis-and-qgis-2-0?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment9071_3739).

Comment: I think the major version number of QGIS is linked to the Python version, and Python4 is not planned for the moment : https://www.techrepublic.com/article/programming-languages-why-python-4-0-will-probably-never-arrive-according-to-its-creator/

Comment: Even then QGIS would still move to a number higher than 3 at some point.