# python-X vs pythonX tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, version-tags

Would it be better to use, for example, [python3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python3) tag instead of [python-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3) because `python3` is the command used to launch python3 on any operating system?

A related and interesting question is
[Tagging Questions that involve Python programming language?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/tagging-questions-that-involve-python-programming-language)

Answer (score 7):

I would opt for sticking with [python-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3) because, as [@MrXsquared has commented](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5101/python-x-vs-pythonx-tags/5103#comment10812_5101), there is a space between "Python" and "3" at the [Python 3.0 Release](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/) home page.

Also, this would keep it aligned with other version tags used here like [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3), [google-maps-api-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3), [arcgis-javascript-api-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-3), etc.

Comment: I think the second part of this answer is the reason it should be kept as-is - _this would keep it aligned with other version tags used here_